# Getting a "this function is empty or cannot be parsed" error for a custom function in flutterflow

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutterflow

I am trying to write a custom function in flutterflow that would allow me to figure out the who owes who how much based on their expenses that is saved in a firebase document.

the firebase document is called transactions, and I first make a dart Map with key:value pairs consisted of each member and the sum of each member's expenses.

the rest of the code uses the splitwise algorithm recommended by chatgpt. It seems that there are no syntax errors, but for some reason I am getting a "this function is empty or cannot be parsed" error.
The following is my code

```
List<String> calculatedebtors(List<TransactionsRecord> transactions)  {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

import 'dart:collection';

class Debt {
  String debtor;
  String creditor;
  double amount;

  Debt(this.debtor, this.creditor, this.amount);
}

  Map<String, double> transactionMap = {};

  // Iterate through the transactions and calculate sums
  for (var transaction in transactions) {
    if (transaction.type == false) {
      String member = transaction.payer;
      double expense = transaction.amount;

      // Update the sum for the payer
      transactionMap[member] = (transactionMap[member] ?? 0) + expense;
    }
  }

  Map<String, double> balances = {}..addAll(transactionMap);

  List<Debt> debts = [];

  while (balances.isNotEmpty) {
    var creditor = balances.keys.first;
    var debtor = balances.keys.last;
    var creditorBalance = balances[creditor];
    var debtorBalance = balances[debtor];

    var minAmount = creditorBalance.abs() < debtorBalance.abs()
        ? creditorBalance.abs()
        : debtorBalance.abs();

    var debt = Debt(debtor, creditor, minAmount);

    if (creditorBalance < 0) {
      creditorBalance += minAmount;
    } else {
      balances.remove(creditor);
    }

    if (debtorBalance > 0) {
      debtorBalance -= minAmount;
    } else {
      balances.remove(debtor);
    }

    if (debtorBalance != 0) {
      balances[debtor] = debtorBalance;
    }

    if (creditorBalance != 0) {
      balances[creditor] = creditorBalance;
    }

    debts.add(debt);
  }

  List<String> debtorsList = [];
  for (var debt in debts) {
    debtorsList.add(debt.debtor);
  }

  return debtorsList;
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

Below is a screenshot for the argument settings
[flutterflow custom function argument settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvTFH.png)

I need help. I tried mostly everything I know, but do consider I am very new to this field and rely heavily on tools such as chatgpt.

Comment: You can't use import statements inside a function. it needs to be at the very top. Also class definitions need to be separate

Comment: But flutterflow would not let me modify code outside a designated area, which is below the defining of the function. Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: I guess it wouldn't be that hard to rewrite the same code to not use a custom class and without needing the import. I'll try to come up with answer in some minutes. But I'm also not familiar with flutterflow, just normal flutter. I don't know if flutterflow allows custom class creation somewhere

Answer (score 0):

The code you got should be identical to this:

```
List<String> calculatedebtors(List<TransactionsRecord> transactions) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  Map<String, double> transactionMap = {};

  // Iterate through the transactions and calculate sums
  for (var transaction in transactions) {
    if (transaction.type == false) {
      String member = transaction.payer;
      double expense = transaction.amount;

      // Update the sum for the payer
      transactionMap[member] = (transactionMap[member] ?? 0) + expense;
    }
  }

  Map<String, double> balances = {}..addAll(transactionMap);

  List<String> debtorsList = [];

  while (balances.isNotEmpty) {
    var creditor = balances.keys.first;
    var debtor = balances.keys.last;
    var creditorBalance = balances[creditor]!;
    var debtorBalance = balances[debtor]!;

    var minAmount = creditorBalance.abs() < debtorBalance.abs()
        ? creditorBalance.abs()
        : debtorBalance.abs();

    if (creditorBalance < 0) {
      creditorBalance += minAmount;
    } else {
      balances.remove(creditor);
    }

    if (debtorBalance > 0) {
      debtorBalance -= minAmount;
    } else {
      balances.remove(debtor);
    }

    if (debtorBalance != 0) {
      balances[debtor] = debtorBalance;
    }

    if (creditorBalance != 0) {
      balances[creditor] = creditorBalance;
    }

    debtorsList.add(debtor);
  }

  return debtorsList;

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

It's actually a mystery to me why there even was a `Debt` class since only the `debtor` was every used of it, so might as well just work directly with the `debtorsList`. I haven't really looked into the algorithm itself so no idea if that one is even correct. In any case I wouldn't just copy code from ChatGPT without understanding what's even happening there.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifiying. I do need the debt class since the final result on the frontend would look like this: personA owes personB $$. I was going to edit the function’s return value to use the other information in the Debt class.